# TortoiseGIT merge conflicts .edmx file error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, git, entity-framework, tortoisegit

I'm trying to merge .edmx file using TortoseGIT, but I am getting to conflicts where I do not know what the codes mean with connectorPoint differences?

See screenshot here:
[image]

Has anyone delt with this?

```
      <ConnectorPoint PointX="5.5" PointY="65.78099659375" />
      <ConnectorPoint PointX="7.7760391666666671" PointY="65.78099659375" />
      <ConnectorPoint PointX="8.1614608333333329" PointY="65.78099659375" />
      <ConnectorPoint PointX="10.40625" PointY="65.78099659375" />
      <ConnectorPoint PointX="10.40625" PointY="64.74949218750001" />
```

Comment: Your *code* does not make sense. It'll be more useful if you could post a *screenshot*.

Comment: screenshot added..  [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1exZpR09eMmvXb9S0PFMrFfEaS4Z03TYsY6S86_wbuzA/edit?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though connectorpoints were added to both branches.  Since there was an addition, git doesn't know which to take (yours or theirs), which is why there is a merge conflict.

You probably want to take both additions, so all the connector points exist, but this may be a trial and error type of problem.  After merging, you can always undo your merge and try again.